# Django Pagination: Loads all elements from first page

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have a page `blog.html`, and pagination sequence loads just fine, but I query the paginator to show one element on a page to test if pagination works. I have 4 items in the DB, the pagination reads 4 elements, but shows all elements on all pages.

**views.py**

```
def blog(request):
    blog_cat = Blog_Categorie.objects.all()
    all_blog = Blog.objects.all()
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(all_blog, 1)
    try:
        blog = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        blog = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        blog = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render_to_response('blog.html',
        'blog':all_blog,'blog_cat':blog_cat,'blog_p':blog})
```

**blog.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
  {% if blog_p.has_other_pages %}
    <ul class="pagination">
      {% if blog_p.has_previous %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ users.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
      {% endif %}
      {% for i in blog_p.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if blog_p.number == i %}
          <li class="active"><span>{{ i }}</span></li>
        {% else %}
          <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% if blog_p.has_next %}
        <li><a href="?page={{ users.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Comment: post your for loop for listing items

Comment: @itzMEonTV my for loop in blog.html is posted already...

Comment: why dont you just loop over `blog_p` ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/

Comment: I feel the paginator class should take care of the queryset from this statement  paginator = Paginator(all_blog, 1). Telling the object to fetch one element from the list all_blogs, i wonder why its listing all elements in my templates..

Comment: It will take care. `paginator = Paginator(all_blog, 1)` and `blog = paginator.page(page)` will take the queryset based on `page`. So you need to iterate over `blog_p` which you are rendering to html

Comment: @itzMEonTV. Thanks, sorted.. It was my oversight. I failed to iterate over 'blog_p' but was iterating over 'blog'

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are iterating over `blog_p.paginator.page_range`. Do iterate over `blog_p`.

For [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/pagination/)